# Automatic insertion of random art to minimize white space?

Tags: graphics, white-space

Are there any packages or tricks for automatically inserting random flourishes or clip art to fill up white space or otherwise ameliorate vertical badness (if that's the right term)?

If not, would it work to queue up a bunch of floats, or would that end up placing them close together in the first few pages?

Comment: floats are queued to avoid adding large white spaces, that is the whole point of the float mechanism. Perhaps you could show an example of why you are getting large spaces, what float options are you using? `[H]` for example requests large white spaces in preference to moving the float.

Comment: I will try first to to reduce vertical badness using `\raggedbottom` and a flexible paragraph skip  (e.g. `\parskip x em plus y em minus z em`) .

Comment: I'm not having any trouble with white space, per se.  It's just that my mostly-two-column document uses sections, sidebars, and whatnot, which results in the occasional choke point where LaTeX can't help but leave a little more white space than I'd like.  Perhaps more importantly, if there indeed is a way to sprinkle decorative images throughout, it would help to reduce the stark blankness on a chapter's final page.

Comment: Is my explanation sufficient?  Maybe what I'm asking for simply isn't possible.